# How can I read the stock data from a Digikey website using Python and Selenium?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, iframe

Here is a sample Digikey website: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/panasonic-electronic-components/ERJ-8ENF2211V/88928?s=N4IgTCBcDaIKICUBSBaAHHAcgMTGAjPgGogC6AvkA

I am trying to read the stock availability data from the above website, which in this case at the time of posting is 42,107. I included a snippet of my code below. There are some extra debugging lines in there that I was using, and I am a total python noob so take it easy :).

The "ENTER MPN" section works just fine and is able to take me to the link I provided above. I added the "Wait for load" section as a precaution early on to make sure things were loaded and I could visually see the data I was trying to capture.

When I try and read the stock availability, I get an error saying the element is not there. I took the Xpath directly from inspecting the line that says the stock amount, so I am fairly certain that is correct. Another interesting thing is that I am able to search and find all the elements in the "Product Attributes" or the Summary section at the top. I am just not able to find any element that is contained in the "Price and Procurement" section. From some reading, I was thinking that maybe this is an iFrame issue where I need to switch to the correct frame, but I have also attempted to cycle through all found iFrames and do a read, but none of that worked either.

Happy to try some ideas!

```
# Enter MPN
search_box_xpath = '//html/body/header/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/input'
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, search_box_xpath)))
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(search_box_xpath)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", search_box)
search_box.send_keys(MPN) # Type in MPN

search_button_xpath = '//html/body/header/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/button'
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, search_button_xpath)))
search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(search_button_xpath)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", search_button)

# Wait for load
time.sleep(5)

# Try and read Stock availability
stockText_xpath = '//html/body/div[2]/main/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]'
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, stockText_xpath)))
print('ELEMENT FOUND!')
stockText = driver.find_element_by_xpath(stockText_xpath)
raw_input('FOUND STOCK TEXT!')
```

Comment: XPATH of "//span[contains(text(), "In Stock")] might do it.  Be aware that if you use an account there this is against their terms of service: "You may not use any robot, scraper, spider, or other automated means to access or gather the Content from the Site, or mirror, co-brand, or frame the home page or any other pages of the Site on any other website or web page."

Comment: Long xpaths like this are very unstable. Are you getting the error on the line `stockText = driver.find_element_by_xpath(stockText_xpath)`?

Comment: The error is actually from the wait command right above that line where it is checking for visibility

Comment: Also even if I search for simpler things (driver.find_element_by_class_name('jss334')) that can be found in the price and procurement section, it still can't find it

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, you should use more robust xpaths.  The below is one example of how you can shorten your xPaths.   The following will open the URL, search for 'MPN' and click the 'In Stock' checkbox

```
driver.get('https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/panasonic-electronic-components/ERJ-8ENF2211V/88928?s=N4IgTCBcDaIKICUBSBaAHHAcgMTGAjPgGogC6AvkA')

search_box_xpath = "//input[@name='keywords']"
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, search_box_xpath)))
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(search_box_xpath)
search_box.send_keys("MPN") # Type in MPN

search_button_xpath = "//button[@class='search-button']"
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, search_button_xpath))).click()
    
stock_availability = "(//span[@class='MuiIconButton-label'])[1]"
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, stock_availability))).click()
```

**EDIT**

I just re-read your question and it is kind of confusing.  If you are just looking for the total stock listed on that direct URL you provided (without searching anything) you can just use the following:

```
total_stock_xpath = "//div[@class='jss195']/div/div"
total_stock = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, total_stock_xpath))).text
print(total_stock)
```

Prints:

```
37,107 In Stock
```

Format for Python 2.7 as you need to